# Foreach loop not exporting to csv

Tags: powershell, foreach, export-to-csv

PowerShell script

```
$(foreach ($k in $sql_output){
    $ip = $k[0]
    $present = $k[1]
    write-output $ip, $present   
}) | export-csv D:\Script\is_present.csv
```

I expect is_present.csv to look like

```
10.10.10.10    1
10.10.10.11    1
10.10.10.12    0
```

Instead it looks like

```
#TYPE System.DBNull
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(foreach ($k in $sql_output){ 
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        'IP' = $k[0]
        'Present' = $k[1]
    }
}) | Export-Csv c:\temp\temp.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The loop is much the same as you had before. `Export-Csv` works better with objects so not knowing where your data came from I made and object with `[pscustomobject]` (*Requires PowerShell 3.0*). Take that data and pass it thru to the next pipe for `Export-Csv`. `-NoTypeInformation` will stop `#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject` from being the first row of the file.

Comment: this answer is most helpful

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
 $(foreach ($k in $sql_output){ 
       $ip = $k[0] 
       $present = $k[1]
       $out = "{0,20}{1,30} -f $ip, $present
       Write-output $out
     }) | out-file D:\Script\is_present.csv
```

Comment: how do I make $ip and $present output on the same line. When I execute this I get one line $ip, next line $present, next line $ip, next line $present, etc

Comment: @walia toumi  Right now, $ip and $present output on same line, but same column. How do I make $ip and $present output on different columns. I tried placing `,` between $ip and $present, but it still doesn't solve the issue